# Why won't pytesseract extract text from this picture of a form?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I wanted to extract the text mentioned in the given Image using the Open Cv and pytesseract library.
[image]

The basic code to extract the text

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'


image = cv2.imread('ruler.jpg')


gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh)


print("Detected Text:\n", text)
```

I believe that the above code would return the text mentioned in the ruler but it givens back random string which is even not present in the ruler image

Btw I am new to python and open cv

Comment: your picture contains nothing "interesting" written on it. it's just the blank "form" and field labels -- you get nothing extracted because tesseract expects the text to be in the right orientation. you have to find the ruler and extract it so it's properly oriented. -- tesseract is not made for recognizing handwriting. you need something else for that. expect nurses to "color outside the lines" when jotting own measurements. best just grab the entire ruler's rectangle and send it to handwriting recog, instead of extracting small regions only.